# What are the preferred dimensions of hi-res Sourceforge project logos?

Tags: retina-display, sourceforge

Recently Sourceforge invited me to upload a high resolution logo for my project, to suit users browsing with a high-DPI display.

However they didn't give any preferred pixel dimensions to prevent rescaling (causing blurring, aliasing), and I don't have such a display.  A search for 'logo' or 'icon' on their blog did not return useful results.  The Sourceforge site documentation only mentions the previous low-res dimensions, 48×48 px.  I have not found any project icons bigger than this (perhaps because of my display).

I do not possess the vector file of my logo, so I will have to order a new rendering from the shop.  So, what dimensions should my uploaded icon have?